# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. Can anybody help me to solve this query?

Tags: sql-server, case

[image: Table structure]

I need to run a query which should display the name of the employees and their salary if the salary is more than 1500. If the salary of the employee is equal to '1500' it should display 'On target' and if it is below 1500 it should display 'Below target'. I ran this query:

```
SELECT ENAME,
CASE
WHEN SALAR < 1500 THEN  'BELOW TARGET'
WHEN SALAR = 1500 THEN 'ON TARGET'
ELSE SALAR
END AS SALARIU_ANGAJAT
FROM EMP
```

And I get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Can anybody help me with a solution? I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **assume** that `Salar` is a **numerical** column. Your `CASE` expression **must return** the same datatype for all possible outcomes - but in your case, you're returning strings for the first two `WHEN` conditions, and presumably a **number** for the `ELSE` case. That won't work.

SQL Server will try to convert **all possible responses** to the same datatype - and the one with the higher precedence is `INT` (or `FLOAT` or whatever) - and thus it tries to convert your strings `BELOW TARGET` to a number --> which of course fails.....

To fix this - ensure that **all** possible outcomes of the `CASE` expression return the **same datatype** - like this:

```
SELECT 
    ENAME,
    CASE
       WHEN SALAR < 1500 THEN  'BELOW TARGET'
       WHEN SALAR = 1500 THEN 'ON TARGET'
       ELSE CAST(SALAR AS VARCHAR(25))
    END AS SALARIU_ANGAJAT
FROM EMP
```